# Can't understand why importing global variables works for running a program and fails for tests

Tags: python, testing, import, global

A little embarrassed asking this because I've been writing python for a while, but apparently I still seem to not fully understand imports. My directory looks as follows (python 3.5, using conda structure):

- app_name/

  - app_name/

    - foo.py
    - sub_dir/

      - bar.py
  - tests/

    - test_bar.py

in foo.py, I have something that looks as follows:

```
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self, test):
        self.test = test
        global my_global
        my_global = self.test
```

and in bar.py, I am able to do: `import app_name.foo as foo_bar`, then in my code I can run `foo_bar.my_global` with no problem.

What I don't understand is why in my test_bar.py, when I test the file 'bar.py' and run the test the global import gives an attribute error. What am I missing??

As for the error: I run 'pytest test_bar.py,' here is the error I get (stack trace from ptest, the **init** is in bar.py):

```
    def __init__(self, test):
>       self.baz = foo_bar.my_global
E       AttributeError: module 'app_name.foo' has no attribute 'my_global'

../app_name/sub_dir/bar.py:39: AttributeError
```

In general, I don't like globals and will eventually fix this implementation. But I figured an explanation of why this is happening would still be helpful. Please let me know if you need more details on the code structure. Thanks!

Comment: The actual error would go a long way towards helping us help you :)

Comment: Even more embarrassing, I didn't add the error! Just updated the question